# Angular и Laravel

Tags: laravel, angular, laravel5, angular5, laravel-5.8

Как использовать одновременно Laravel и Angular при разработке веб приложения?

С работой двух данных фреймворков сталкиваюсь впервые, поэтому вопрос может показаться глупым.

После старта Angular сервера командой `ng serve --open` Angular автоматически работает на порту 4200. После старта Laravel он работает на порту 8000.

Вопрос - как соединить Laravel и Angular и заставить их работать на каком-то одном порту?

Как правильно это реализовать? Интересуют все тонкости. Благодарю!

Comment: На одном порту - никак (можно, но сложно и нафиг не нужно). Laravel должен предоставлять API а Angular долен с этим API работать. Сами приложения могут быть вообще на разных серверах запущены.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб предположим, я запустил Angular и Laravel. Angular запускается на порту 4200 (localhost:4200), Laravel на 8000 (localhost:8000). Я отправляю из Angular приложения запрос, скажем, на /api/action. И Angular (так как порт 4200) делает запрос на localhost:4200/api/action. Следовательно, Laravel не обработает этот запрос, так как он висит на другом порту (8000). Как их в этом плане подружить?) Я конечно могу прописать чтобы Angular делал запрос конкретно на 8000 порт, но, как мне кажется, такая реализация не совсем правильная...

Comment: Тут два пути. Можно вот так прокси настроить: https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d. Второй вариант - прописать явно порты. Мне кажется удобнее 2 вариант, т.к. можно просто для dev/prod вариантов сборки прописать разные порты.

Comment: Всё можно сделать, просто надо использовать прокси, в ангуляре это есть

Answer (score 0):

Зачем тебе делать чтобы лара и ангулар работали на одном порту ?

Если ты делаешь SPA приложение, то будет правильно разделить фрон и бэк.
Отдельно подымаешь ангулар и общаешься с бэком посредством API.

Вот пример реализации простого SPA с использованием лары и ангулара

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/10/23/php-laravel-angular-crud-app